# How to get get IE to remember you new website password

Tags: internet-explorer-8, password-management

When you change your password for a web site that you login to, how can you get IE to use the new password. I have changed my password for a password-protected site I use and IE keeps filling on the old password.

I'm using IE8

Comment: Umm… don't use IE?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Nirsoft's IE PassView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/internet_explorer_password.html) to view your saved passwords. Then you can delete the old (stored) password for that site, and the next time you try to log in that site, IE will ask you whether you want to save your new password. Just say Yes and that's all.